# Is it safe to return and modify primitive values during func return

Tags: go

(question reworded based on discussion, original question below)

The [Go Language Specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation) gives examples showing that order of evaluation for primitives is unspecified with respect to function calls during assignment to slices and maps. None of the examples mention multi-value return though, so I'm not sure if they apply in this case or not.

Examples from the spec

```golang
a := 1
f := func() int { a++; return a }
x := []int{a, f()}            // x may be [1, 2] or [2, 2]: evaluation order between a and f() is not specified
m := map[int]int{a: 1, a: 2}  // m may be {2: 1} or {2: 2}: evaluation order between the two map assignments is not specified
n := map[int]int{a: f()}      // n may be {2: 3} or {3: 3}: evaluation order between the key and the value is not specified
```

Using the language of the spec, is [this functions](https://go.dev/play/p/fahthLKqeNH) return also unspecified:

```golang
func run() (int, int) {
    a := 1
    f := func() int { a++; return a }
    return a, f() // always return 1,2 OR always returns 2,2 OR can return either?
}
```

If the order of evaluation is not specified then a non-toy example like the following could break at some time in the future if the compiler is updated:

```golang
func CountRows(ctx context.Context, db *pgxpool.Pool) (int, error) {
  row := db.QueryRow(ctx, "SELECT COUNT(*)")
  var count int
  return count, row.Scan(&count)
}
```

**Original Question**

I'm unclear whether the go language specification is clear on whether values returned from funcs are "returned" one at a time or once all expressions are evaluated.

Aka is [this code](https://go.dev/play/p/cBqM85D2aQC) guaranteed to always output `10 <nil>` (as it does in the playground) or can it ever output `0 <nil>`?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(run())
    // Output: 10 <nil>
}

func run() (int, error) {
    var i int
    return i, inc(&i)
}

func inc(i *int) error {
    *i = *i + 10
    return nil
}
```

**Edit**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006089/in-go-when-are-values-copied-in-multivalue-assignments) related question suggests that order of evaluation of the primitive return value is not specified by the specification

Comment: I meant always as in independent of compiler version/supplier. I will update the question to be more specific

Comment: In my head the compiler could be interpreting the return as `ret1 := i; ret2 := inc(&i); return ret1, ret2` which would result in `0 <nil>` and was ambiguous for me. The spec says that order of evaluation of primitives is not defined and gives examples of structs and maps but not return statements so I'm unclear if the spec covers this case

Comment: you're obfuscating your question, this is a much simpler case showing the order of evaluation https://go.dev/play/p/3m7dyhmqx-Y. Evaluation of the individual operand expressions happens left-to-right, and only then do you evaluate `Println` (or the `return` statement in your case).

Comment: I don't understand how or if your example is different from the specifications "unspecified" examples https://go.dev/play/p/NG-mBzlZFLc - specifically I don't know if the "unspecified" examples in the spec also apply to return statements

Comment: I'm just saying that your original question structure made it difficult to understand, there is no "during return", and asking about evaluation vs assignment might have been clearer. Change the arguments to assignment, and you can see the rhs is evaluated first https://go.dev/play/p/zuNvsiN0j1K. If you still think the spec is unclear here, the mailing list and issue tracker are better places for the discussion.

Comment: Apologies for the unclear question, my intent was not to ask about rhs vs lhs order, it was about the reliability of the order of execution for the arguments on the rhs in a multi-value return. The spec only lists examples where order is unspecified for slice and map and I wasn't sure if it was also unspecified for primitives in return.

Comment: If you’re writing something like `count, row.Scan(&count)` as non-toy  production code you already have problems regardless of spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "Is this function return also unspecified?"

Yes. As you found, the language specifies the evaluation order for some things:

> when evaluating the operands of an expression, assignment, or return statement, all **function calls**, **method calls**, and **communication operations** are evaluated in lexical left-to-right order.

Naturally, anything that is not a function call, method call or communication operation is left unspecified with respect to evaluation order in an expression, assignment or return statement.

2. "a non-toy example like the following could break at some time in the future if the compiler is updated"

Yes. Even if the compiler doesn't update. If you expect it to have any particular result that's reliant on evaluation order, then the code is already broken in the sense that the language does not say the code will do what you think it will do.

3. "are values returned from funcs "returned" one at a time or once all expressions are evaluated."

There is no such distinction to be made.

4. "is this code guaranteed to always output `10 <nil>` (as it does in the playground) or can it ever output `0 <nil>`?"

Yes, it can output `0, <nil>`. This is essentially the same as the previous `run` example, where now the closure `f` has been refactored as a function called `inc`.

Comment: Thank you for the direct and concise answers to my questions

Answer (score -1):

Yes! This is a really great question.

Another way to write this code is

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(run())
    // Output: 10 <nil>
}

func run() (int, error) {
    var i int
    err := inc(&i)
    return i, err
}

func inc(i *int) error {
    *i = *i + 10
    return nil
}
```

This is the same reason why you can do the following

```
func main() {
    callIt()
}

func callIt() (int, error) {
    return multiReturn()
}

func multiReturn() (int, error) {
    return 0, nil
}
```

And additionally, you can do this as well, which can be useful if you wrap a db transaction (for example) in an error handler

```
func main() {
    result, err := assignInReturn()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // the result here, assuming no error occurred, will be 1...
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func assignInReturn() (int, error) {
    var i int
    return i, wrapErrFunc(func() error {
        // db call
        if err := dbCall(); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        i = 1 // ...because of this. This will set `i` to 1 before `assignInReturn` returns to its caller
        return nil
    })
}

func wrapErrFunc(fn func() error) error {
    return fn()
}

func dbCall() error {
    // db query
    return nil
}
```

In these situations, you can be certain that the items in the top-level `return` will evaluate prior to being returned to its caller